# JCarousel Lite (multiple carousel issues)

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, css, jcarousel

I'm making attempts to install multiple JCarousels onto my project.

http://natesmithen.com/wired/test/test.html

as you can see I've made attempts to add a second carousel however it seems to be blocking out the javascript, are there any specific variables I need to call out in my javascript in order for this to work, if so what are they?

Also is the a way I can get this carousel to scroll in reverse?

I've a plugin from the following site:

http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/

Comment: You can load more than 1 carousel on the page.  Can you post your code what are you trying to do ?

Comment: Here's the download link with my files    https://rapidshare.com/files/3238336180/test_site_files.zip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nate,

You're not calling the second Carousel as you have a typo:

```
<div class="carsouel2">
```

Where as you call:

```
$(".carousel, .carousel2 ").jCarouselLite({
```

So make the div:

```
<div class="carousel2">
```

Try that.

Al

Answer (score 1):

Just checked the test.html file.  Seems like you are calling a different class.

```
 <div class="carsouel2">
```

But you initialized as different class name

```
$(".carousel, .carousel2 ").jCarouselLite({
```

One more thing this is not related to carousel, this is related performance.  You are trying to load jquery files twice.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script> //CDN File
<script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> // Local File
```

Always use the cdn URL as compared to using the local jquery file.